# How do I transfer assigned tasks in one sheet to another sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

Okay I know about the scripting thing in Google Sheets, particularly the ImportRange function. However, it's not just a simple import since there are conditions that have to be met.

So here it goes.
In one Google Sheets file, I have 5 sheets.

Sheet 1 contains the tasks and details, indicated in columns A-P (so it's taking one whole row). Tasks are assigned to one person based on what's indicated in column Q's data validation options.

Meanwhile, for Sheets 2-5, they are the sheets for each person in the data validation options. The tasks in sheet 1 should be transfered to sheets 2-5, based on whoever it is assigned in Column Q of sheet 1.

In the work process POV, it's going to be about traffic. What code should I put in the script editor?

[spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsJxY.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example that you can build upon:

```
function assignTask() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var today=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MMM dd, yyyy");
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++){
    if(!vA[i][3]){
      var sht=ss.getSheetByName(vA[i][2]);
      if(sht){
        sht.appendRow([vA[i][0],today]);
      }else{
        var sht=ss.insertSheet(vA[i][2]);
        sht.appendRow(['Task','Date'])
        sht.appendRow([vA[i][0],today]);
      }
      vA[i][3]='Done';
      vA[i][1]=today;
    }
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```

Spreadsheet Looks like this:

[image]

After running the script is looks like this:

[image]

> If the person's sheet doesn't exist it will create it and put header information in it after creating it.  If it exists the row is just appended to the bottom.  Tasks that are assigned have "done" in the assigned column and a date they were assigned in the date column.  Obviously, there are a lot of other things you can do with this so have fun with it.

**To answer your question:**
Your function copies columns.

```
function copyColumns() {
  var srcSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Total"); 
  var desSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Cooked"); 
  var cA = ['A','C','D','F']; 
  var pA = ['A','B','C','D']; 
  for(var i=0;i<cA.length;i++){
    srcSheet.getRange(cA[i] + ':' + cA[i]).copyTo(desSheet.getRange(pA[i] + ':' + pA[i]));
    //src colA to des colA, src colc to des colB,src colD to des colC,src colF to des colD 
  }
}
```

**Checkout these References:**

1. [Spreadsheet Range Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
2. [Spreadsheet Sheet Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

Comment: Thanks Cooper! What does the code below mean?

function copySheet() {
  var sourceSheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Total");
  var destSheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Cooked");

  var columns_to_be_copied = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'F'];
  var columns_to_be_pasted = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

  for (column in columns_to_be_copied) {

    var copy_range_string = columns_to_be_copied[column] + ':' + columns_to_be_copied[column];
    var paste_range_string = columns_to_be_pasted[column] + ':' + columns_to_be_pasted[column];

Comment: var source = sourceSheet.getRange(copy_range_string);
    var destination  = destSheet.getRange(paste_range_string);
    copyTo(source,destination );
  }
}